# Android Studio, centralizar o nome da aplicação

Tags: android-studio

[image: Print Android Studio]

[image: Imagem do Código]

Como faço para centralizar o texto circulado ?

Answer (score -2):

Use o `display: flex` junto com o `justify-content:` center em um elemento pai.

Assim exibira o resultado que você espera, veja no exemplo que deixei abaixo.

Espero ter ajudado.

```css
#id-text{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="id-text">
  <h1>GroupTCC</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: Mas o arquivo está dentro do AndroidManifest.xml onde acredito  que essa formatação não seja valida, vou anexar foto do código na pergunta

Comment: tem uma pergunta  [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43468761/how-to-align-center-action-bar-tittle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43468761/how-to-align-center-action-bar-tittle)
parecida tente ver se te ajuda

Answer (score -2):

01 - Crie um Layout em 'layout' + 'New' + 'Layout Resource':

```
<com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Lista - ListView 1.0"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />
```

02 - Na 'Activity.kt' correspondente, digite:     getSupportActionBar()?.setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM)
getSupportActionBar()?.setCustomView(R.layout.layout_title)

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).